# Mixed tense sentences

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? Or better to say, is there any part in the sentence with wrong grammar?

Have you ever started thinking of someone while walking to somewhere which then made you smile?

If yes, what would be the correct one?

Comment: There are no grammatical errors as such, but it isn't well expressed. I assume you mean that 'thinking of someone' causes the smile, but your sentence could be read as 'somewhere which made you smile'. I would suggest "Have you ever, while walking somewhere, had a thought about someone which made you smile?"

Comment: Note, as Kate illustrates, that idiomatically people **walk somewhere** and not **to somewhere**, although they can walk **to** any place, site, village, city etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few different ways you could express this that may be unclear. For example: Did the place you are going to make you smile? Did you smile upon thinking of the person or is it that you thought of someone who had once made you smile?

To make it very clear, I would express it like this (especially in speech):

> Have you ever been walking somewhere and then suddenly thought of someone and it made you smile?

I like the sequential aspect of this phrasing, and feel it makes the meaning quite explicit. I also think it has a bit of a storytelling aspect to it, and would keep the listener engaged.

I used the word “suddenly” as I imagine you’re talking about a thought randomly (another word you could use) popping into your head and also the significance of that seeming to happen more frequently when you’re walking somewhere.

Comment: You know what? I wanted it to look a bit more complex by using "relative clauses", which makes it a little bit complicated. That's why I didn't use "and".

Comment: I see. For me, there are too many opportunities to jumble things up, so I’d keep it simple. @KateBunting has given a good way to phrase this, but although it’s something I’d write, I can’t imagine I’d ever say it that way.